# How to get the latex phrase \sqrt[n]{x} onto matplotlib?

Tags: text, matplotlib, latex

A radical with an arbitrary base seems supported by latex without external libraries, but matplotlib's mathtext can't parse it. Is there anyway I can get matplotlib to display it?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you writing? To parse with LaTeX, you need to write `r'$\sqrt[n]{x}$'`, do you have that?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm writing. It gives me a ParseFatalException error. Going by mpl's documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/mathtext.html#radicals) they don't seem to support by default arbitrary letters when they say that "the base must be a simple expression, and can not contain layout commands such as fractions or sub/superscripts".